# Referring to wildcard characters in mv operation

Tags: bash, wildcard, mv

This is my bash code:

```
mv ./foo*foo2*foo3*.foo3 ./foo*.foo3
```

How can I refer to the second wildcard character from `./foo*foo2*foo3*.foo3`  when renaming my file using the `mv` command?

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Maybe I'm using incorrect terminology? If so, please let me know.

Comment: You can't directly, shell expansion doesn't provide any such feature. Look for tools called "rename"

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow that already deal with renaming multiple files in a single batch; try searching with "bulk rename".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) tool is just for that:

```
sh$ touch fooAfoo2Bfoo3C.foo3
sh$ rename -v 's|foo.*foo2(.*)foo3.*\.foo3|foo$1.foo3|' *.foo3
#                         ^^^^                ^^
#                     capture the           insert
#                   second "wildcard"  --->  here
fooAfoo2Bfoo3C.foo3 renamed as fooB.foo3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below rename command on the directory where the original file is located.

```
rename 's/^.*\./foo\*\./' *.foo3
```

It renames `foo*foo2*foo3*.foo3` file to  `foo*.foo3`